# Radiobutton when selected show div and make required

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a Magento website and there are some delivery options when ordering a product.

There are 2 methods available. 
- pick up yourself
- deliver

When you choose radiobutton "deliver" some div with a textarea is visible.
This textarea needs to be required.

But when you select radiobutton "pick up yourself" the textarea is invisible and needs to be NOT required anymore.

[I made a fiddle of the items](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/gv7xh4cg/1/)

Can anyone help me with how to do this?

---

HTML:

```
<h2>Select delivery method</h2>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" name="shipping_method"> pick up
    <input type="radio" class="radio" checked="checked" id="s_method_tablerate_bestway" value="tablerate_bestway" name="shipping_method"> deliver

<div id="deliv-hold">
    the delivery date and time:<br>
    <textarea id="shipping_arrival_comments" name="shipping_arrival_comments" style="min-width: 265px;" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not using the jQuery Validate plugin, so you should not be using the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after a pure js version you can use this method:

```
function check() {
    var items = document.getElementsByName('shipping_method');
    var v = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].checked) {
            v = items[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    var required = (v == "tablerate_bestway");
    document.getElementById("deliv-hold").style.display = required ? "block" : "none";
    if (required) {
        document.getElementById("shipping_arrival_comments").setAttribute("required", true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shipping_arrival_comments").removeAttribute("required");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gv7xh4cg/9/

Basically, iterate over items of the same name and see if they are selected, if they are grab the value from it and use that to show or hide the comments div.

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: thanks, I also found a way to do it but the most important actually is to get the textarea required when selecting the deliver button. I think that will be difficult.

Comment: Udpated to set the "required" attribute based on selection

Comment: thanks, I can't really test if this will work because there is no submit button. I will try Zerapots answer first

Comment: Added a submit button. :)

Comment: when select pick up the textarea is still required  :(

Comment: Updated to remove attribute... Heh heh... :)

Comment: I really hate magento, somehow magento strips out the script when I add it. I add the text: test and below it the script, all I get in the source is test and no script... really really weird.. I think because of the ajax script the onepage checkout uses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69619/discussion-between-marc-and-ian-harrigan).

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see an example of code to do so :

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var submitMessage = "";
  
  $(":radio").change(function() {
    var selectedRadio = $("input[name='shipping_method']:checked").val();
    
    if (selectedRadio == "freeshipping_freeshipping") {
      $("#deliv-hold").hide(250); 
    }
    else {
      $("#deliv-hold").show(250); 
    }
  });
  
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    
    var selectedRadio = $("input[name='shipping_method']:checked").val();
    
    if (selectedRadio == "freeshipping_freeshipping") {
      submitMessage = "Your command is in process. Thank you for purshasing.";
    }
    else {
      if ($("#shipping_arrival_comments").val().length < 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Field 'delivery date and time' missing.");
        submitMessage = "";
      }
      else {
        submitMessage = "Deliver is on his way. Thank you for purshasing."; 
      }
    }
    
    if (submitMessage != "") {
      alert(submitMessage); 
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test check </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>Choose your delivery method :</span>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" name="shipping_method"> 
      <label for="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping">Pick up yourself</label>
      <input type="radio" class="radio" checked="checked" id="s_method_tablerate_bestway" value="tablerate_bestway" name="shipping_method"> 
      <label for="s_method_tablerate_bestway">Deliver</label>
    
    <br />
    <div id="deliv-hold">
    the delivery date and time:<br>
    <textarea id="shipping_arrival_comments" name="shipping_arrival_comments" style="min-width: 265px;" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
      <input type = "submit" id="submit_delivery" name = "submit_delivery" />
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used JQuery include (see below the code the script include) to use the DOM selector which is easier to use than plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks allot Zeratops, the validation is the most important. The textarea needs to be filled with at least 1 character. Else when submit you need to get a popup or other message. That is what I mean with required.

Comment: Snippet have been updated for the validation. + Editing the snippet to not display delivery message when no text is typed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it in the magento form. the submit button looks like this: <button onclick="shipping.save()" title="Go on" class="button" type="button"> hope it works.

Comment: It will, because if the form is not correct, the `e.preventDefault();` will prevent from submit the form, so no data is sending and the behaviour of the submit button is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle (it also makes the textarea required):

http://jsfiddle.net/gv7xh4cg/4/

You should include jQuery for:

```
$('input.radio').click(function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();

    var delivlHold = $('#deliv-hold'),
        comments = $('#shipping_arrival_comments');

    if(selectedOption === 'freeshipping_freeshipping') {
        delivlHold.show();
        comments.prop('required',true);
    } else {
        delivlHold.hide();
        comments.prop('required',false);
    }
});
```

and than add display: none:

```
#deliv-hold{padding-top:20px; display: none}
```

It does what you asked for.

Comment: your correct, it needs little tweaking, on start the deliver is visible and required, when pickup no textarea and not required. After adding a submit button it didn't work correct. I like this script thow

Comment: Yes, I like to keep things plain and simple, as for adding the submit button,  this was just to do what you initially asked, but with a little tweaking it can easily be fitted in. Anyway, I see you've got your code so won't bother to edit this :) Cheers